# Spritekit collision detection. Node moving so fast a collision occurs without any visual touching

Tags: sprite-kit

Any one else ever had this problem. I have two nodes moving towards each other. When i ramp up the speed that they move at, when a third node tries to pass in between them as the first two nodes comes together, it detects a collision even though you can see that none of the nodes ever touched. Im using precise collision detection as well. Is their anything else i can do.

Comment: so  A ----> C <------B  at no point does A hit B's track, and B hit As track, and you are saying that C collides?  or does A and be in fact overlap while c is making its course through them

Comment: @Knight0fDragon A collision is set off when a and b touch c. A and B move at the same speed and C is right in the middle, so a and b should touch c at the same time. The frame right before the frame where a and b would be on top of c is when the collision is detected. The collision is being detected one frame to early. The detection is going off before a and b can have there position be updated. So it never actually looks like c was touched.

Comment: How are you verifying that it is touching one frame too early?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It just looks like its 1 frame to early. When a detection occurs, the nodes are removed and the scene is left. Is it possible that when a collision occurs, the nodes are getting removed before there position is updated. Does the collision method have a higher priority over a single frame.

Comment: Yeah, thats what was happening. The bars never had the chance to update there position when a collision occurs, so it was just looking like a collision never happened. I took the scene transition out of the collision method and put it in the update method and replaced it with a boolean and its working as expected now.

Comment: drawing is one of the last stages of the update process,  so when a collision happens,  you will never see it happen if you remove it in the beginning or middle of the process.  There is a method called `didFinishUpdate` that you need to override,  and you remove all your nodes there.  This way it draws the final frame, then removes

Comment: I just took a look at the flow chart,  like I got my order messed up.  you need to kill the nodes after rendering is complete,  didFinishUpdate happens before it.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we nailed down the issue,  I am going to post it as an answer:

What is happening is during your update phase,  you are removing all of your nodes that are involved with the collision,  so you will never see them touching.

What you need to do instead,  is keep track of what nodes will be removed (a nice array of SKNode works fine) then at the beginning of the Update phase, immediately check if removed nodes is not empty.  if it is not empty,  then you need to go through it and remove them from the scene.

Example:

```
var removeNodes = [SKNode]()
...

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
   if(removeNodes.count > 0)
   {
     for node in removeNodes
     {
       node.removeFromParent()
     }
   }
   removeNodes.removeAll()
}
... normal update code




...at some point after collision
//node A needs to be removed
removeNodes.append(nodeA)
```